# Load nivo-type slider only if screen is above certain size

Tags: javascript, html, css

Many professionally designed templates incorporate a form of slider (eg Slider Revolution, nivo etc) for home pages.

Although they might be responsive, I find that when testing them on mobile devices the animation often isn't very smooth and can slow down loading and processing times. In some instances, the ongoing animation in the slider seems to interfere with the display and scrolling of the page depending on the quality of the phone.

So, I'd like to retain the slider for desktop machines but not for handheld devices.

As I understand it, if the slider's in a containing div (div#sliderWrap, say) I could easily set the slider to simply be invisibile (display: hidden) if I were to use CSS3 media queries.

However, this would still mean the slider would still load and all the objects in it because they're in the main HTML, thus still slowing down the page loading time ans using unnecessary data usage.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use an iframe, and then load the slider into the frame only when the screen size was above a certain width, eg 960px? I imagine this might be done with javascript/jquery.

So, I suppose my aim would be to have an iframe on the home page with a bit of js saying, if the page is greater than 960px, load slider.html into the iframe. Slider.html would contain all the slider info that would normally appear in the html of the home page, including the javascript the slider needs to function.

If anyone could advise on this I'd be most grateful, or perhaps just your thoughts on alternatives? My javascript knowledge is minimal as you might have gathered - my expertise is largely in html4 and css2 and I'm only just catching up! - so please accept my apologies if my vocabulary isn't as precise as perhaps it should be a in a forum such as this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS media query to check the screen size and change styles accordingly. For example, you could use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 960px) {
/* put slider code in here */
}
```

This would mean that the slider styles are only used when the window width is at least 960px. You could use this to hide the slider elements, but it'd still load the JS file for the slider functionality. You could use jQuery to only load the script when the window is at least 960px like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(document).width() > 960) {
        var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = "url of slider JS file";
        $("#sliderElement").append( script );
    }
});
```

Hope that's not too confusing!